# when I install jupyterlab-kite build error

Tags: node.js, npm, jupyter-lab, kite

OS:

> Mac OS

python:

> Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 16:54:48)
> [Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin

pip:

> pip 19.0.3 from /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

install `jupyter-kite` with: `jupyter labextension install @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite`
**output**:

```
Node v14.8.0

> /usr/local/bin/npm pack @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite
npm notice
npm notice   @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0
npm notice === Tarball Contents ===
npm notice 1.5kB  LICENSE
...
kiteco-jupyterlab-kite-1.2.0.tgz


   ╭────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                                                │
   │      New patch version of npm available! 6.14.7 → 6.14.8       │
   │   Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v6.14.8   │
   │               Run npm install -g npm to update!                │
   │                                                                │
   ╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯

Node v14.8.0

> node /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab/staging/yarn.js install
yarn install v1.9.4
info No lockfile found.
[1/5]   Validating package.json...
[2/5]   Resolving packages...
warning @jupyterlab/application > @jupyterlab/coreutils > comment-json > json-parser@1.1.5: `json-parser` is deprecated. Please use `comment-json` instead
warning @jupyterlab/application > @jupyterlab/apputils > react > fbjs > core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
warning @jupyterlab/faq-extension@0.19.1: The JupyterLab FAQ extension is no longer developed and is removed from JupyterLab 1.0.
warning @jupyterlab/json-extension > react-json-tree > babel-runtime > core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
⠄ p-defer@^1.0.0
⠠ shebang-regex@^1.0.0
⠁ shebang-regex@^1.0.0
⡀ isexe@^2.0.0
⠈ @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@file:../extensions/kiteco-jupyterlab-kite-1.2.0.tgz(node:22770) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
⠈ vscode-jsonrpc@^4.1.0-next
⠂ vscode-languageserver-protocol@3.14.1
⢀ vscode-languageserver-types@3.14.0
⠐ @fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types@^0.2.32
⠂ react-transition-group@^4.4.1
⡀ prop-types@^15.6.2
⠐ prop-types@^15.6.2
⠁ prop-types@^15.6.2
warning css-loader > cssnano > autoprefixer > browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
warning css-loader > cssnano > postcss-merge-rules > browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
warning css-loader > cssnano > postcss-merge-rules > caniuse-api > browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
warning webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
warning webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar > fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
warning webpack > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
warning webpack > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
[3/5]   Fetching packages...
warning vscode-languageclient@5.2.1: The engine "vscode" appears to be invalid.
[4/5]   Linking dependencies...
warning "@jupyterlab/vdom-extension > @nteract/transform-vdom@1.1.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^15.6.1".
warning "@jupyterlab/vega4-extension > vega-embed > vega-lite@2.7.0" has unmet peer dependency "vega@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
warning "@jupyterlab/vega4-extension > vega-embed > vega-themes@2.9.1" has unmet peer dependency "vega@*".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/application@2.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/apputils@2.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/cells@2.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/codeeditor@2.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/codemirror@2.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/completer@2.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/coreutils@~4.0.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/docmanager@2.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/docregistry@2.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/fileeditor@2.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/notebook@2.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/rendermime@2.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/services@5.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@jupyterlab/statusbar@2.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/tooltip@2.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@lumino/algorithm@*".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@lumino/widgets@*".
warning "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/application@~2.0.0".
warning "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/apputils@~2.0.0".
warning "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/codeeditor@~2.0.0".
warning "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/codemirror@~2.0.0".
warning "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/coreutils@~4.0.0".
warning "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/docmanager@~2.0.0".
warning "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/docregistry@~2.0.0".
warning "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/fileeditor@~2.0.0".
warning "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/notebook@~2.0.0".
warning "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/observables@~3.0.0".
warning "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/services@~5.0.0".
warning "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@lumino/algorithm@*".
warning "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite > jupyterlab_toastify@4.1.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^16.6.0".
warning "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite > jupyterlab_toastify > react-toastify > react-transition-group@4.4.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@>=16.6.0".
warning "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite > jupyterlab_toastify > react-toastify > react-transition-group@4.4.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@>=16.6.0".
[5/5]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
warning Your current version of Yarn is out of date. The latest version is "1.22.5", while you're on "1.9.4".
✨  Done in 175.96s.
> node /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab/staging/yarn.js run build
yarn run v1.9.4
$ webpack
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@jupyterlab/statedb' in '/Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite/lib'
    at /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:535:10
    at /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:397:22
    at /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21
    at /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22
    at /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2830:7
    at /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:6877:13
    at /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25
    at /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:213:14
    at /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7
    at /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43
    at /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:28:1)
    at /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/ModuleKindPlugin.js:30:40
    at /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/forEachBail.js:30:14
    at /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7
    at /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
resolve '@jupyterlab/statedb' in '/Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite/lib'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite/package.json (relative path: ./lib)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite/lib/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/@kiteco/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/ricardo/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite/node_modules
        using description file: /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
      looking for modules in /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules
        using description file: /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/@jupyterlab/statedb)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/@jupyterlab/statedb)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite/node_modules/@jupyterlab/statedb doesn't exist
            .wasm
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/@jupyterlab/statedb doesn't exist
            .wasm
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite/node_modules/@jupyterlab/statedb.wasm doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/@jupyterlab/statedb.wasm doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite/node_modules/@jupyterlab/statedb.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/@jupyterlab/statedb.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite/node_modules/@jupyterlab/statedb.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/@jupyterlab/statedb.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite/node_modules/@jupyterlab/statedb.json doesn't exist
              /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/@jupyterlab/statedb.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite/node_modules/@jupyterlab/statedb doesn't exist
            as directory
              /Users/ricardo/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/@jupyterlab/statedb doesn't exist
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

what should I do? I'm should my kite service is running normal.